# Grails and Oracle Anydata

Tags: oracle, grails

I'm trying to create a simple Groovy & Grails interface to an Oracle table that (among a few other columns) contains 1 column of datatype ANYDATA. (I am new to G&G so please bear with me.)

Although the domain class easily allows me to map the column to sqltype "sys.anydata", the controller doesn't seem to be able to handle this. I get the typical error:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got CHAR

Since dealing with Oracle anydata columns can be tricky, this doesn't surprise me, and there may be a lot of grails side work to get it functional.

First off, I'm guessing I need to override the save method of the controller in order to get the String converted to ANYDATA for a successful insert. Not even sure where to start here...typically in oracle SQL you would use something like:

INSERT into mytable (id, anydatacol) values (1, sys.anyData.convertVarchar2('mystring'))

in your INSERT SQL to get a string inserted into anydata.

How would I customize a controller to insert like above (using some function on the field) instead of the canned save method?

I'd love to see a working example of grails and an anydata, but regardless of how far I get with using anydata with grails I am curious about how to customize a controller like above.

---

---

Thanks so much that seems very helpful!

Making some progress. Everything compiles but when I run-app I get:

```
Running Grails application
| Error 2013-10-17 22:33:29,123 [startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - could not complete schema update
Message: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2002
    Line | Method
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run       in java.lang.Thread
| Server running. Browse to
```

My db is Oracle 11g, I'm using the dialect org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect...tried 11 too and that throws the same errors.

Is there some other config I need to do to use the custom usertype? From the link you posted, I created a class. Besides that, my class looks like:

```
class Anytest {

    String name
    AnyScalarData anytdat

    static mapping = {
        table 'ANYTDAT'
        anytdat type:AnyScalarData, sqltype: "sys.anydata"

    }


    static constraints = {
        name(blank:false)
        anytdat(nullable:true)
    }
}
```

EDIT:

updated Config.groovy with:

grails.gorm.default.mapping = {    'user-type'( type:AnyScalarDataUserType, class:AnyScalarData )}

but now getting:

```
Running Grails application
| Error 2013-10-17 23:01:27,441 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsDomainException: Error evaluating ORM mappings block for domain [anydata_01.Anytest]:  No such property: AnyScalarDataUserType for class: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingBuilder
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsDomainException: Error evaluating ORM mappings block for domain [anydata_01.Anytest]:  No such property: AnyScalarDataUserType for class: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingBuilder
    Line | Method
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsDomainException: Error evaluating ORM mappings block for domain [anydata_01.Anytest]:  No such property: AnyScalarDataUserType for class: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingBuilder
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

Comment: Any other ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

### Using DomainClass: Creating a custom UserType

Grails uses Hibernate under the hood. I searched but not found a mapping type for Oracle's `ANYDATA`, so you need to implement a [custom User Type](http://omaha-seattle.blogspot.com.br/2010/02/grails-hibernate-custom-data-type.html). Basically it will translate to Hibernate how to sotre and retrive from the database your column.

[Here's a example](http://system-repository.googlecode.com/svn-history/r31/trunk/org.kb.uml2/org.kb.uml2.core.model/src/main/java/org/kb/hibernate/usertype/AnyScalarData.java) that I've found with a UserType that works with ANYDATA.

### Using sql

Since you're new to Grails, it's worth mentioning that you can also use SQL directly, without using a domain class. Example of service:

```
class MyService {
  def dataSource

  void addNewRecord(String data) {
    groovy.sql.Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)
    sql.execute("insert into my_table(my_anydata_clomn) values(sys.anyData.convertVarchar2(?))",[data])
  }

}
```